# Confidence Band for a function of the derivative and the value of the cumulative distribution function?

Tags: probability, distributions, confidence-interval

I am calculating a value that is computed by dividing the derivative of the cumulative distribution function by the value of the distribution function at that point. It is of the form:

$J = \frac{F'(x)}{F(x)} $

Where $F(x)$ is the cumulative distribution function. To get the confidence band on $F(x)$ I can use the [DKF Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvoretzky%E2%80%93Kiefer%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_inequality). **How do I get the confidence bands on J?**